# Typescript, Mongoose and Intellisense

Tags: typescript, mongoose, intellisense

I was trying to find and elegant way to get Intellisense and typing working with mongoose documents that I wrap in a class to implement business logic. This is the solution I've come up with, which feels a little hacky, but seems to work. Is this ok or is there a better way?

The critical and hacky feeling part is this `type UserDocument = IUser & Document<IUser>;`

```
import mongoose, {Document, model, Schema} from "mongoose";

interface IUser {
  firstName: string
}

const userSchema = new Schema<IUser>({
  firstName: {type: String, required: true}
});

const DbUser = mongoose.models.User || model<IUser>('User', userSchema);
type UserDocument = IUser & Document<IUser>;

export class User {
  private userData: UserDocument = new DbUser();

  public set firstName(value: string) {
    this.userData.firstName = value;
  }

  public get firstName() {
    return this.userData.firstName;
  }

  public static async createFromDocument(document: UserDocument): Promise<User> {
    const user = new User();
    user.userData = document;
    return user;
  }

  public async save(): Promise<void> {
    await this.userData.save();
  }
}
```

Comment: This question is more suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many project i use this template to build the model and types and make intellisense recognize it:

```
import { Schema, model, Types } from 'mongoose';
import { ApiScanDocument } from './interfaces/index';

const ApiScansSchema = new Schema({
    apiKeyId: {
        type: Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    scans: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
}, { toJSON: { virtuals: true }, toObject: { virtuals: true } });

ApiScansSchema.virtual('apiKey', {
    ref: 'ApiKey',
    localField: 'apiKeyId',
    foreignField: '_id',
    justOne: true
});

const ApiScan = model<ApiScanDocument>('ApiScan', ApiScansSchema);

export { ApiScan }
```

and now the type:

```
import { Document, Types } from 'mongoose';

export interface ApiScanDocument extends Document {
    apiKeyId: Types.ObjectId;
    scans: number;
}
```

this is really similar to yours but make all docs finded using findOne or find methods of mongoose have from default the type

Comment: I think `interface IUser extends Document` is nicer than `type UserDocument = IUser & Document<IUser>;`